# Prove that E is a connected space

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ and $A_i$ ($i \in I$) be connected spaces such that $A\cap A_i\ne\varnothing$ for $i \in I$.

How to show that $E = A \cup \bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ is a connected space?

Comment: You have to clarify your question somewhat-is this a general topological space or some subspace of $R^n$ with the usual topology or some other topology?

Comment: the general one !

Comment: Try proving the similar statement for 2 sets. If you can give your thoughts on that, then people here might be more inclined to help you.

Comment: I still not find the solution  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A space $X$ is connected iff every continuous $f: X \rightarrow \{0,1\}$, where the codomain has the discrete topology, is constant. This is easy to check from the definition of connectedness.

Now let $f: A \cup \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ be continuous.

As $f|_A$ is continuous and $A$ is connected, there is some $c_A \in \{0,1\}$ such that $f(x) = c_A$ for all $x \in A$.

Now fix an arbitrary $i \in I$. We know that $f|_{A_i}$ is continuous and $A_i$ is connected, so we have $f(x) = c_i \in \{0,1\}$ for all $x \in A_i$. But as there is some $p \in A \cap A_i$ we know that $c_A = f(p) = c_i$, and this holds for any $i$. This means that $f(x) = c_A$ for all $x \in A \cup \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$, so $f$ is constant and this sset is connected.

Comment: Creative proof! My proof is more cumbersome,but it has the advantage of working from first principles. They complement each other nicely.

Comment: thanks you I love the 2 demonstrations !!!!

Comment: So where's my +1,Jenny?

Comment: The continuous function approach is quite elementary, its proof is two lines, basically

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Not for a beginner-which the OP clearly is.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is whether or not the nondisjoint union of 2 connected subsets of a topological space is itself connected. Recall the definition of a connected subset of a topological space.

Def: A topological space X is said to be disconnected if it is the union of two disjoint nonempty open sets. Otherwise, X is said to be connected i.e. if there are $A,B\subseteq X$ and if $A\cup B$ = X, then at least one of the following holds (i) $A \neq\emptyset$ or $B \neq\emptyset$. (ii) Either A is not open or B is not open. (iii) $A \cap B =\emptyset$ . A subset of a topological space is said to be connected if it is connected under its subspace topology.

Ok, so let's see. Since A is a connected subset of X, there exists a family of disjoint open sets in A with the subspace topology, ${E_i}_{i\in I}$ such that $\bigcup_{i\in I}E_i= A$. Also, since ${E_i}_{i\in I}$ is open in the subspace topology, there exists a family of open sets of X, ${B_h}_{h\in H}$ such that for every $i\in I$ and $h\in H$, $E_i =A\cap B_h $. Similarly, there exists a family of sets of X $A_i$ for every i, ${F_j}_{j\in J}$ such that $\bigcup_{j\in J}F_j$=$A_i$ and there exists a family of open sets of X, ${D_k}_{k\in K}$ such that for every $j\in J$ and $k\in K$, $F_j =A_i\cap D_k $. Therefore $\bigcup_{i\in I}\bigcup_{j\in J}F_j$=$\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$.

So let's assume $ G\subseteq X$ where $G =A \cup \bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ =  $\bigcup_{i\in I}E_i \cup \bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$=$\bigcup_{i\in I}E_i \cup\bigcup_{i\in I}\bigcup_{j\in J}F_j$. Since for every $i\in I$, $E_i =A\cap B_i $, then $\bigcup_{i\in I}E_i$=$\bigcup_{i\in I}(A\cap B_h)$.Similarly, $j\in J$ and $k\in K$, $F_j =A_i\cap D_k $,so $\bigcup_{i\in I}\bigcup_{j\in J}F_j$ =$\bigcup_{i\in I}\bigcup_{j\in J}(A_i\cap D_k)$  So G = $\bigcup_{i\in I}E_i \cup\bigcup_{i\in I}\bigcup_{j\in J}F_j$=$\bigcup_{i\in I}(A\cap B_h)\cup\bigcup_{i\in I}\bigcup_{j\in J}(A_i\cap D_k)$=$(A\cap \cup_{i\in I}B_i)\cup(\cup_{j\in J}A_j\cap \cup_{i\in I}D_i)$. This last rather complicated expression is a union of relatively open sets in G and it states moreover that both A and $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ are open in G.Therefore G is a union of relatively open sets.

Also, since  $A\cap A_i\ne\varnothing$ for $i \in I$, then $\bigcup_{j\in J}F_j \cap \bigcup_{i\in I}A_i \neq\emptyset$ for every $j\in J$. Lastly,since $A\cap A_i\ne\varnothing$ for $i \in I$,then both subsets of G must be nonempty since otherwise,  $A\cap A_i=\varnothing$ for $i \in I$. But this means G is not a union of 2 disjoint open sets and therefore G is a connected subspace of X and we're done! Q.E.D.

Ok,I'm crawling to bed to die now. You're welcome. Hope I didn't waste all that time and make a mistake-if I did,believe me,we'll both hear it tomorrow.